# Use Identified Column Dynamically In Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have been able to identify a column based on certain criteria, but now I need to use the identified column in a statement to find the last non-zero value and insert a row after that value. I have not been able to figure out how to use the dynamic column in the statement; help please. Also, if there is a better statement to use to find the last non-zero value, then please tell me. Thank you in advance.

("I" is the static column that I would like to change to a dynamic column)

```
Dim i As Long
i = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Do Until Range("I" & i) <> 0
i = i - 1
Loop
'MsgBox Cells(i, 1).Address
Cells(i, 1).Select
Selection.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

Comment: Use `Cells()`: `i = Cells(Rows.Count,9).end(xlup).row` then you can replace the `9` with a variable that has the column number.

Comment: Then do I change the Do Until Range...to Do Until Range(maxCol & i) <>0 'the maxCol is what my column number is?

Comment: no you need to change to `Cells()` : `Do Until Cells(i,maxCol) <>0`

Comment: Scott - THANKS!!! That worked!